# How can I see nth-child's background-color after page break?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm creating printing page and I'll need to avoid table to break. That's why a new page is created if the table is breaking. However, after the page break, I can't see background-colors of nth-child.

Avoid table to break:

```
table {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
     break-inside: avoid;
}
```

And for the nth-child I tried this:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgb(235,237,237);
}
```

After page break I expected to see background colors but somehow cannot see those.

Comment: Its difficult to see what you want please create an example with [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o862fmqn/3/ So this is what I mean, look at that second page. You can see tthat table, but you cannot see thos background colors

Answer (score 0):

If it is only occurring during print then you may need to add exact print color adjust property, as colours are ignored by default.

```
@media print{
    body{
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```

I replicated your problem and after applying that setting, it fixed it for me, so I hope this helps. Also keep in mind that if there is a background color set to any `<td>` it will hide the `<tr>` background-color.

**EDIT**
Adding `z-index:-1` and `position: relative` to the second page fixed the issue.

```
<page class="second-page">
```

```
.second-page{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: So this is what I mean: jsfiddle.net/o862fmqn/3

If you look at that second page, somehow those background colors are under that second page. Same happens when I'm on the "printing"-page. That css-code din't help.

Comment: I messed around with the fiddle and by applying z-index: -1, and position: relative to the second page, I was able to get the background-colors working. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9htdu5x6/1/